# Node js app session. How to make users did not intervene in the session to each other?

Tags: node.js, session

I learn node js. I got very simple app, where need to type query to videohostings. E.g. you type "cat" and page shows you video with some cat. Nevermind.

I use express, and I really can't understand how works sessions and cookies. I want make different sessions for each user. Sorry for my silly English, now I'll write it literally :D

If one user entered a query and he was given a video, the other user should not see the result of his query, i.e. it must have the same result

Because if I have already type the query and the video display, the same displayed on the other browser, it turns out that some kind of "common search".

Hope you understood, thanks for replies!

UPD, 
There are taking query from input and put it to variable, that need for pug template to link to video that need to insert to page

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {

    if(!req.body) {
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }

    vk.request('video.search', {'q' :req.body.query}, function(_o) {
        query = _o.response.items[0].player;
        res.redirect('back');
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no session built inside node.js, you have to build your own, or use a middleware. For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-session

Comment: It's not clear why a session would help in the situation you're describing. Share the relevant part of the code, so we can better understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

After you have installed it you need to configure it like so:

```
const session = require('express-session')({
    secret: 'your secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
```

Afterwards you need to make sure your `app` uses it (`app` should be `app = express()`). To make the code use `express-sessions` you need to do `app.use(session);`

To access your sessions all you have to do when routing is get the `session` object from the `request` parameter.

In idea it would look like so for saving:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    req.session.yourvariable = 'foo';
});
```

To get the session variable its as simple as doing `req.session.yourvariable`

Comment: Oh, it works, thanks. I had tried do same with session-cookie.